# How to compare case insensitive string using FluentAssertions? C#

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

How can I easy compare string case insensitive using FluentAssertions?

Something like:

`symbol.Should().Be(expectedSymbol, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);`

Edit: Regarding possible duplicate and code:
`symbol.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedSymbol);`

it is comparing using CurrentCulture. And it will brake in situation like Turkish culture. Where 
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR", false);
string upper = "in".ToUpper(); // upper == "İN"
"in".Should().BeEquivalentTo("In"); // It will fail`

so the part "*StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase*" is crucial here.

Comment: Why don't you just call `.ToLower()` on the string you're comparing against?

Comment: @Glubus looking for a better way. Note that when you use `ToLower()` and it fails, FluentAssertions will raport changed values (lowercased).

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
symbol.ToLower().Should().Be(expectedSymbol.ToLower());
```

OR

Instead of `Be` use `BeEquivalentTo`

```
symbol.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedSymbol);
```

`BeEquivalentTo` metadata states

> Asserts that a string is exactly the same as another string, including any leading or trailing whitespace, with the exception of the casing.

Comment: It is nice but, as I added in the question it will fail for Turkich culture.

Comment: Then use the duplicate questions accepted answer. `symbol.Should().Equal(expectedSymbol, 
    (o1, o2) => string.Compare(o1, o2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: ToLower or ToUpper should almost never be included as part of a string comparison solution. It will fail for many languages. Plus it performs slower because it iterates over the string multiple times and increases heap allocation. I hope no one copies that into their code without first thinking about the consequences.

Comment: Btw, this comment found in Github regarding FAv7 from Dec-18-2022: `...we then replace the BeEquivalentTo on string with Be and an overload of Be that takes a StringComparison`  https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/2064#issuecomment-1356734362